# js "for in" not appending key/values in a specific order

Tags: javascript

Given the following literal:

```
"rating":{
"overall": 89,
"atmosphere": 82,
"cleanliness": 91,
"facilities": 86,
"staff": 94,
"security": 91,
"location": 91,
"valueForMoney": 90
},
```

And the following `for/in` loop:

```
for (key in data.rating) {
  if ( key != "overall" ){
    //<div class='ratingbar'><p>" + translateRating(language, key) + "<span class='right bold'>" +  data.rating[key]/10 + "</span></p><div class='bar-wrapper'><div class='bar' style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></div></div></div>
    //current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, key) + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating[key]/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></span></div></li>");
    if ( key == "valueForMoney" ){
      current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, 'valueForMoney') + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating[key]/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></span></div></li>");
    }
    if ( key == "security" ){
      current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, 'security') + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating[key]/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></span></div></li>");
    } 
    if ( key == "location" ){
      current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, 'location') + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating[key]/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating[key] + "%'></span></div></li>");
    }                           

  }
}
```

When I print the values of the object, I'm expecting them to print in a specific order—the same order as my if statements. Instead, "valueForMoney" is always last. The order I'm expecting is:

1. Value For Money
2. Security
3. Location
4. Staff
5. Atmosphere
6. Cleanliness
7. Facilities

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/4341456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys in an object are not guaranteed to be in order; you'll need to either use an array or a Map to make sure they're in the right order.

If you can, converting your data structure to be an array of objects is the simplest solution:

```
"rating": [
    { name: "overall", value: 89 },
    { name: "atmosphere", value: 82 },
    ...
]
```

since you can then loop through them in a guaranteed order.

You could also try [converting the object to a Map](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html), although Maps only exist in ES6 so you'd need to transpile if you;re not already. The [order of keys in Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is guaranteed to be the order in which they're inserted, so this would work for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Properties order is not guaranteed in JavaScript.

Definition of an Object from ECMAScript 3

> #### 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

ECMAScript 6

> #### 9.1.11 [[Enumerate]] ()
>
> When the [[Enumerate]] internal method of O is called the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Return an Iterator object (25.1.1.2) whose next method iterates over all the String-valued keys of enumerable properties of O. The Iterator object must inherit from %IteratorPrototype% (25.1.2). **The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified** but must conform to the rules specified below.

Answer (score 1):

How about just printing like this without *for key in* ?

```
 current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, 'valueForMoney') + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating.valueForMoney/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating.valueForMoney + "%'></span></div></li>");
 current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, 'security') + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating.security/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating.security + "%'></span></div></li>");
 current.find('.ratings ul').append("<li class='left'><span class='ratinglabel'>" + translateRating(language, 'location') + "</span><span class='ratingpercent bold'>" + data.rating.location/10 + "</span><div class='ratingbackground rounded'><span style='width:" + data.rating.location + "%'></span></div></li>");
```